# Ant design DatePicker in form

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, antd

I'm using `DatePicker` component from `antd` inside a form and want to change the default `onChange` and `value` of props in `DatePicker` but it is not working.

```
<Form.Item
  label='Test Label'
  name='startDate'
  getValueFromEvent={(onChange) => moment(onChange).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
  getValueProps={(i) => moment(i)}
>
  <DatePicker format='YYYY-MM-DD' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
</Form.Item>
```

When I use `DatePicker` outside of the form it works:

```
<DatePicker value={moment()} style={{ width: '100%' }} />
```

Is this a problem with `getValueProps` prop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed it!

In case that anyone has same issue:

you have to change `getValueProps` to something like this:

```
getValueProps={(i) => ({value: moment(i)})}
```

Comment: The date can be undefined and `moment(undefined)` results in current date. This equals to setting the default value to current date. Use `getValueProps={(i) => ({ value: i === undefined ? undefined : moment(i) })}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**For Ant Form:**

```
<Form.Item
        name="dateOfBirth"
        label={t('date_of_birth')}
        rules={[{ type: 'object', required: true, message: t('this_field_is_required') }]}
        defaultValue={moment(user.dateOfBirth)}
        getValueProps={(i) => ({ value: moment(i) })}
    >
        <DatePicker
            format='DD/MM/YYYY'
            placeholder='DD/MM/YYYY'
            allowClear={false}
        />
</Form.Item>
```