# TypeError: date.locale is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using antd `"antd": "^5.5.1"` DatePicker to bind a date string, this is the `App.tsx` code looks like:

```
import { DatePicker, Form } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export interface EduModel {
  admission: String;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [edu, setEdu] = useState<EduModel>();

  const onFinish = (values: any) => {

  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let edu1: EduModel = {
      admission: '1995-09-01'
    };
    setEdu(edu1);
  }, []);

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo: any) => {

  };

  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue(edu)
  }, [form, edu]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        size="large"
        form={form}
      >
        <Form.Item
          label={"admission"}
          name="admission"
          rules={[
            { required: true, message: "please input date" }
          ]}>
          <DatePicker format={"YYYY-MM-DD"}></DatePicker>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when I run this simple page, shows error:

```
dayjs.js:185 Uncaught TypeError: date.locale is not a function
    at Object.format (dayjs.js:185:1)
    at formatValue (dateUtil.js:104:1)
    at useValueTexts.js:18:1
    at useMemo (useMemo.js:5:1)
    at useValueTexts (useValueTexts.js:8:1)
    at InnerPicker (Picker.js:150:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
```

I have tried to add the DatePicker string format, but still could not fixed this issue. Am I missing something? what should I do to make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71594682/ant-design-datepicker-in-form

Answer (score 0):

###### date.locale error ant datepicker

I think Ant Datepicker accept dayjs type or string at version 5, can not accept undefined. initially your form's value is undefined. update it later string.

Could you pls try like that?

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-mccarthy-6qfjhw)

when you set inital value :

```
form.setFieldsValue({
 admission: dayjs(edu?.admission)
});
```

when you submit value:

```
const onFinish = (values: any) => {
 console.log({
  ...values,
  admission: dayjs(values?.admission).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
 });
};
```

hope that can help you.

```
import { DatePicker, Form, Button } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";

export interface EduModel {
  admission: String;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [edu, setEdu] = useState<EduModel>();

  const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    console.log({
      ...values,
      admission: dayjs(values?.admission).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let edu1: EduModel = {
      admission: dayjs("1995-09-01").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    };
    setEdu(edu1);
  }, []);

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo: any) => {};

  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (edu) {
      form.setFieldsValue({
        admission: dayjs(edu?.admission)
      });
    }
  }, [form, edu]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        size="large"
        form={form}
      >
        <Form.Item
          label={"admission"}
          name="admission"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "please input date" }]}
        >
          <DatePicker format={"YYYY-MM-DD"}></DatePicker>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```